# Regex to match everything between (potentially multiple) pairs of tags

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I know this question has been somehow asked before, and I know that Regex are not really suitable to manage XML. Though, I am using them in a python utility with `re.compile(...).subn(...)` to substitute some XML content without parsing the XML itself, since this XML content is inside proprietary/legacy language files. Thus, XML tools are not an option and regex is the last resort before thinking about writing a specific algorithm.

I need to substitute something (an attribute value) contained inside an element. 
E.g., from:

```
<Tag>
bla bla
<SomethingElse AnAttribute="YEAH"/>
bla bla
</Tag>
```

To:

```
<Tag>
bla bla
<SomethingElse AnAttribute="AH,NO!!"/>
bla bla
</Tag>
```

To perform the match I tried both the simple pattern (with non-greedy operator):

```
<Tag>(.*?)AnAttribute="(.*?)"(.*?)</Tag>
```

And the one with non-greedy operator + negative lookahead:

```
<Tag>(?!Tag)(.*?)CurrencyCode="(.*?)"(?!Tag)(.*?)</Tag>
```

They both work for the simple cases (the last one better handles "false positives"), but I still can't handle the following (pretty simple!) case:

```
<Tag></Tag>
bla bla 
<SomethingElse AnAttribute="YEAH"/>
bla bla 
<Tag></Tag>
```

Since in this case `AnAttribute` **is** actually spotted (and **it shouldn't** as it's not inside the element)!!

Comment: *since this XML content is inside proprietary/legacy language files* - so if you can isolate the XML, then parse it, then put it back, would that work?

Comment: nope, because it's "xml like", full of spurious characters and markers making the xml completely invalid... It would take ages to parse it and put it back in the same way.

Comment: If I've learned anything about regex, I've learned to not match tags.

Comment: @AlexGidan: if the solution provided works for you please accept it. Otherwise provide a failing example so that i may eventually improve the solution to match your criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to split the problem in two steps:

1. **Extract** the relevant section of text inside the desired tag
2. **Replace** the attributes inside that tag

This can be done pretty using `re.sub` with a closure passed as parameter.

The following use `partial` to pass extra parameters to the closure and builds also the the needed regex dynamically:

```
import re
from functools import partial

text = u'''
[...]
'''
# The key is the external tag to extract
# The value a list of attributes whose content has to be replaced
sub_dict = {"RoomRatesWithoutServices": ['CurrencyCode1', 'CurrencyCode2'],
            "AnotherTag": ['AnotherAttr']}

replacement = '_REPLACED_'


def closure(attr, replacement, m):
    attr_pattern = '(?<=(?:%s)=")[^"]+(?=")' % attr
    return re.sub(attr_pattern, replacement, m.group())

for ext_tag, attr_list in sub_dict.iteritems():
    attr = r"|".join(attr_list)
    tag_pattern = r"(?s)<%s>.*?</%s>" % (ext_tag, ext_tag)
    text = re.sub(tag_pattern, partial(closure, attr, replacement), text)

print text
```

The output is the following:

```
'<RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
  </RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>&
  <RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
</RoomRatesWithoutServices>&'

'<RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" CurrencyCode1="_REPLACED_"/>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" CurrencyCode2="_REPLACED_"/>&
  <RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
</RoomRatesWithoutServices>&'

'<RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
  </RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" CurrencyCode="EUR"/>&
  <RoomRatesWithoutServices>&
</RoomRatesWithoutServices>&'

'<AnotherTag>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" AnotherAttr="_REPLACED_"/>&
  <TotalBeforeTaxPayHotel AmountAfterTax="560.00" AnotherAttr="_REPLACED_"/>&
  <AnotherTag>&
</AnotherTag>&'
```

Try the online [DEMO](http://ideone.com/6Owt3b)

Comment: Hello @GsusRecovery, I tried it and it still **does** pick up also the wrong value.

Comment: I tried your option, but the problem is it doesn't work with groups, as you can see in my demo. It's really weird, I'm not understanding why my pattern doesn't work, it's the same as yours (except for the groups)...

Comment: @AlexGidan: i've splitted the problem in 2 steps and provided a working solution, let me say if it works for you.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the effort. Secondly, it works (but without the complication of having a `.join(attr_list)`, because if the attributes are of different length then we fall into a `variable size lookahead exception`. I think I could accept your answer, but I am still asking myself it there is really not a more direct solution relying only on regex.

Comment: @AlexGidan: the join is used only for convenience (and it works in the example, if you can details the exception case maybe this can be fixed). Anyway you can always pass the attribute_list as a parameter to the closure and cycle over it or this can be rewritten with matching groups without relying on lookahead / lookbehind to anchor the pattern.

Comment: @AlexGidan: if you use only the ``re module`` this is the way to accomplish your task. The single regex approach is possible but not in a general way: you can handle only a finite number of matching groups (and then of attributes) inside the chosen tags. With the new python regex module you can find them all (with the ``matches.captures`` method) but you can't replace them without a lambda and the match string offset/length anyway.

Comment: thanks for the deep insight and explanations. I think your approach is the most appropriate for the problem I described.

Comment: @AlexGidan: thank you. Consider in the code above there is a caveat. i've used the lazy modifier to select the text inside the desider tag. If you have the same tags nested inside itself, the regex select from the first tag to the first closing tag (this is a general problem of the regex with XML). So if we want to replace ``title`` with ``TITLE`` inside ``<h1>``: ``<h1><h1>title</h1>title</h1>`` -> ``<h1><h1>TITLE</h1>title</h1>`` (we lost the last ``title``). Maybe it's a remote case but it's better know it's a possibility.